# Why does my jQuery selector fail after a dialog is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-dialog

I'm tearing my hair out with this jQuery selector problem.  I wrote some code so that when the user drags a file into the page, it pops up a jQuery dialog that shows the list of files that have been dragged in with some buttons for managing the list.  If that dialog is open, then the next file that gets dropped in should update the dialog (which is currently open).  The code is like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var updateDialog = function () {
            ....
            $("#my-selector").text(getMyString());
    }; 
    setDragDropHandler("#main-dropzone", function (f) {
           doSomethingWithFiles(f);
           $("#my-dialog").dialog("open");
   });
   $("#my-dialog").dialog({
           ...
           open: function () {
                 updateDialog();
                 setDragDropHandler("#dialog-dropzone", function (f) {
                          doSomethingWithFiles(f);
                          updateDialog();
                 });
           }
   });
});
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that my `setDragDropHandler` takes a selector for a div that it replaces with a div that says "Drop files here" using `replaceWith` while the files are being dragged, but then replaces it when the files are dropped. `#my-selector` is a child of `#dialog-dropzone`, so it ends up getting replaced.

When I drag the first file in, the dialog opens fine and puts in the right text in #my-selector.  When I drag a subsequent file in, while the dialog is open, `$("#my-selector")[0]` is undefined, so the dialog doesn't update.  If I do the following, it works as expected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stupidHack = $("#my-selector");
    var updateDialog = function () {
            ....
            stupidHack.text(getMyString());
    }; 
    // rest is the same
});
```

As you can tell by my variable name, I'm not a fan of this solution.  Can anyone explain why version one fails?

Comment: Any chance this can be packed into a fiddle?

Comment: Without having much context on the project, I could pose an argument that, depending on the complexity of your page, it is more efficient to do the "stupid hack" and get a reference to your element instead of having to scan the DOM to find #my-selector whenever you update.

Comment: @sabof right now, there are too many files in the current page... I'll see if I can try to reproduce with a simple fiddle

Comment: @Vizkos Fair enough... but for my own edification, then, any idea why it would fail?

Comment: Assuming I understand correctly, the issue is only present when #my-dialog is open.  I would suggest trying to select #my-selector with a parent element as well, so like $("#my-selector", "#someParentOnTheDOM") and seeing what happens.  Also worth verifying if #my-selector was not some how removed from the DOM.

Comment: @Vizkos *sigh* I found it...

Answer (score 0):

Blah, my drag and drop handler was calling the callback before replacing the DOM elements.  Oops...